# How to change the format of a datagrid column that would show the time only

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, time, format, datagridviewcolumn

Im creating a software that inputs the time the data was gathered, but in the data grid view it also shows the date. worse is it displays the date in the year 1988. How do I change the format?

Comment: Is this a DataGridView in Winforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-Click on the datagridview and select Edit Columns. Select the column used to display time and properties, scroll up to Appearance and click `DefaultCellStyle`. Click the `[...]` button and set the Format to `hh:mm:ss tt`

You can also click the `[...]` in the `Format` which will open the Format String Dialog where you can select `Date Time` and select the format you would prefer.